# Doxygen generatred call graphs on overloaded operators

Tags: c++, doxygen

I use Doxygen to generate call graphs for my c++ code.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to get nodes of overloaded operators to be included in the call graphs. The following example has a class `Foo` with an overloaded `operator()` and a `normalFunction()`. Running Doxygen on this sample successfully generates the call graph from `main()`-->`Foo::normalFunction()` but not for `main()`-->`Foo::operator()`

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    void operator()(){}      
    void normalFunction(){}
};

int main()
{
  return 0;
  Foo foo;
  foo();                  //Doxygen DOES NOT include overloaded operator in call graph
  foo.normalFunction();   //Doxygen does include the normal function in the call graph
}
```

I have been scouring the Doxyfile parameters without success. Am I doing something wrong or is this feature simply not supported?

Comment: Does doxygen include other overloaded operators?

Comment: Doxygen includes the normal function documentation for the overloaded operators, but none of the operators I have tested so far work in the call graph generation.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using ?

Comment: The latest official release 1.8.13.